# elasticsearch7.10 get to know what query matched

Tags: elasticsearch

I have mappings

```
'properties' : {
    'names' : {
        'types' : 'text',
        'fields' : {
            'suggest' : {
                'type' : 'search_as_you_type',
            }
        }
    },
    'aliases' : {
        'type' => 'nested',
        'properties' : {
            'names' : {
                'type' : 'text',
                'fields' : {
                    'suggest' : {
                        'type' : 'search_as_you_type',
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And want to make autocomplete for 'names' and 'aliases.names'. Using next query

```
GET people/_search
{
  "query": {
    "dis_max": {
      "queries": [
        {
          "function_score": {
            "query": {
              "multi_match": {
                "query": "nic",
                "type": "bool_prefix",
                "fields": [
                  "names.suggest",
                  "names.suggest._2gram",
                  "names.suggest._3gram"
                ]
              }
            },
            "field_value_factor": {
              "field": "rating"
            },
            "boost_mode": "replace"
          }
        },
        {
          "function_score": {
            "query": {
              "nested": {
                "path": "aliases",
                "inner_hits": {},
                "query": {
                  "multi_match": {
                    "query": "nic",
                    "type": "bool_prefix",
                    "fields": [
                      "aliases.names.suggest",
                      "aliases.names.suggest._2gram",
                      "aliases.names.suggest._3gram"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "field_value_factor": {
              "field": "rating"
            },
            "boost_mode": "replace"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "names.suggest": {
      }
    },
    "fragment_size": 10,
    "pre_tags": [
      ""
    ],
    "post_tags": [
      ""
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to show original name if query matched it and original name + alias it it matched alias and didn't match name. For example:

Nicol Fernand (Jame Fernand, Tom Fernand)

For query 'Fern' I need to show 'Nicol Fernand', for 'jam' I need to show 'Nicol Fernand (Jame Fernand')

Highlighting doesn't work in this case. How can I get this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [named queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-named-queries-and-filters.html) like so:

```
{
  "query": {
    "dis_max": {
      "queries": [
        {
          "function_score": {
            "query": {
              "multi_match": {
                "_name": "matched_names_field",      <--
                "query": "nic",
                ...
```